# How do I install svn?

Tags: apt, software-installation, svn

I am trying to install svn and am running into issues.  The command I am running is `sudo apt-get install svn`.  When I run this, I get the error "Unable to locate package svn".  Why is this?  How do I fix it?

Comment: in such cases I would open synaptic and type 'svn' in the searchbox

Comment: in such cases I would run `apt-cache search subversion`

Answer (score 247):

The package is called [subversion](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/subversion)  (abbreviated `svn`). You've to install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

This package contains the `svnserve` daemon too (not started by default). If you want to host a subversion server over HTTP, you must install `apache2` and configure it accordingly.

Comment: Is there a client only package as well? Or you have to install the server as well.

Comment: @Martin The server binary (`svnserve`) is only 85 KiB, the administration tool `svnadmin` is 72KiB. Their manpages are some KiB. Just install the `subversion` package to get all subversion programs (`svnserve` "server", `svn` client (256KiB)). You do not need a server like Apache for the client functionality.

Answer (score 21):

There is no package with the name of SVN .
You may type this command on terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Then you can check it using svn command

```
svn co "type here your checkout URL without double quotes"

svn status 

svn commit ...........your file name
```

Answer (score 6):

apt-get is an amazing package manager, but often the names of packages aren't exactly named the way you would expect. (Obviously not the fault of apt-get) for example, downloading java isn't `apt-get install java`.
as for your issue,  the name of the svn package in apt-get is subversion.

`apt-get install subversion`

have fun with your subversion needs!