# How can I install the Social-Engineering Toolkit (SET)?

Tags: software-installation

There is this software (SET) from Backtack 5 source that I found out about. But I don't know how to install this thing. Could somebody help me?

Here the link:

http://www.secmaniac.com/download/

Answer (score 3):

As the install instructions on the page you linked to say:

First:

- be sure to [install subversion](https://askubuntu.com/q/55546/7163) before installing the selected tools

Then as root:

```
svn co http://svn.secmaniac.com/social_engineering_toolkit set/
```

Comment: I think it's possible that either installing Subversion or running `python install.py` is the step giving the OP problems if he's having trouble with the site's directions. Can you expand on those a little (i.e., how to install Subversion and how to get to the correct directory where the `install.py` script would be located)?

Comment: The python bit was specific to artillery - on re-reading I realised the OP was just looking at SET. So I have added a link for installing subversion.

Comment: can you tech me step by step in to install his.What is subversion?

Comment: @iehJulianec The specific command to install Subversion (a [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) program) via the Terminal is `sudo apt-get install subversion`, as provided by the [top answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/55548/18612) of the linked question. Alternatively, it can be found by searching for it in the Ubuntu Software Center. You need Subversion in order to run the command listed in the above answer, which checks out a copy of the software repository containing SET.