# How can I install subversion client in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, svn

I have looked at this question:

- [How do I install svn?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55546/how-do-i-install-svn)

We use `sudo apt-get install subversion` to install subversion on the server.

What should I do in order to install the subversion client?

SVN client is only needed and we don't need the server on all machines.

Also we don't need GUI access on Ubuntu machines.

Comment: Hi Priya. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The subversion package that you have installed on the server pretty much includes the client items. So, you can just go ahead and install it on the clients as well. And it is not GUI as well. So, I am sure it is more than enough for your need. If you want to discuss this, you can join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Comment: This kept failing for me until I ran: sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe multiverse"

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your question in fact contains the answer.

1. Install the subversion commandline tool using `sudo apt-get install subversion`.
2. Use the client by typing the command `svn command [options] [args]`.
3. Do not do anything else. The server will not start and you can happily use the client without the server. You will also not have GUI access.

The `subversion` package

> includes the Subversion client (`svn`), repository administration tools
>   (`svnadmin`, `svnlook`) and a network server (`svnserve`).

Installing the whole packages (including both server and client) *might seem* like a lot of overhead, but it is the most **easily maintainable solution**. You easily get future updates, security releases and more. Also if ever one of your users desperately needs a subversion server, it is only a few commands away.

Use `svn --version` for the modules included:

```
* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
```

and use `svn --help` for more information. The available commands illustrate that the `subversion` package is the way to go.

```
   add
   blame (praise, annotate, ann)
   cat
   changelist (cl)
   checkout (co)
   cleanup
   ...
```

You could also install `svnkit`, but that comes with a lot of `java` dependencies. Here is the official screenshot for the package (you can find it in `synaptic`):

[image]

For more information read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ and http://subversion.apache.org.

Answer (score 3):

Use [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/)
RabbitVCS is a set of graphical tools written to provide simple and straightforward access to the version control systems you use. 
Currently, it is integrated into the Nautilus and Thunar file managers, the Gedit text editor, and supports Subversion and Git, with a goal to incorporate other version control systems as well as other file managers.

It is primarily inspired by TortoiseSVN.

RabbitVCS is Free/Open Source Software written in the Python and is based upon the PyGTK library.

Answer (score 2):

When you look what files are installed for the package `subversion` you'll that the package contains both client and server:

```
> dpkg -L subversion
…
/usr/bin/svndumpfilter
/usr/bin/svnserve
/usr/bin/svnversion
/usr/bin/svnlook
/usr/bin/svnrdump
/usr/bin/svnmucc
/usr/bin/svnsync
/usr/bin/svn
/usr/bin/svnraisetreeconflict
/usr/bin/svn-rep-sharing-stats
/usr/bin/svnadmin
…
```

So one possibility is using `Post-Invoke` to remove the server file after installation.

1. Create a new file `99remove-svn-server` with `sudo` in directory `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`.
2. Add the following line

   ```
   DPkg::Post-Invoke {"if [ -e /usr/bin/svnserve ]; then rm /usr/bin/svnserve; fi";};
   ```

Every time you use `apt-get` (or other installation methods), it will call the script after finishing its actions. This small scripts looks if `svnserve` exists and if yes, removes the file.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion package includes svn (Subversion client) also. So you don't need to worry. If you want a GUI use [Rabbit](http://rabbitvcs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As dedunumax said, the subversion package includes both client and server, but according to another answer on askubuntu ([How do I install svn?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55546/how-do-i-install-svn)) the server (daemon) is not started by default.

Theoretically this should mean that installing the subversion package should be all you need to do on client machines.